# seeking statistical measures to use when evaluating a facial photo's "quality"

Tags: clustering, confidence-interval, sampling

I have a large set of facial photos and a facial feature finder which helps me locate faces with a general idea of the location of the eyes, nose, mouth, and a curve outlining the face. These facial photos come from a web service, of course, and I want to make quality assessments of the face images in the photos. With the quality assessments, the web service's end-users can be coached to provide better images.

I'm thinking of three measures that require looking at the photo's pixels. But I am unclear on the correct way to calculate some of them. I am only concerned with the pixels over the face.

1. Is the image noisy? This most often happens in conditions of low
   illumination.
2. Is the image over lit? This is harder than it sounds because fair skinned redheads photograph very bright images, so just looking for an over abundance of brightness does not work.
3. Is the image unevenly lit? This is the easiest to detect, and I don't think
   I need help with that.

I'm currently generating a crude skin tone measure, where I sample skin RGB, convert to HSV (hue, saturation, brightness), and then accumulate and average the terms with logic  throwing out samples overly bright - considering them highlights. My logic "detecting highlights" is very basic: it throws away bright pixels. What would be a better method?

With photos of low illumination, the skin samples tend to be very noisy. How can I detect this? Likewise, the web service users are directed to remove their hair from their face, but few of them actually do; I expect any measures of "noise" in the skin areas could be impacted by hair - both locks and stray hairs - in the skin sample areas. How to detect this?

I'm working in C++, but actually have 7 semesters of college statistics rotting in my brain, and no issue with implementing whatever is necessary - did it before...

Essentially, I'm right at the beginning of taking an ad-hock "solution" into the real world with formal statistics. But I'm not really sure where I should be looking for solutions to some of these issues. I was thinking a simple confidence interval for throwing away non-skin pixels, but then low illumination photos proved that technique a non-solution. Do I need to get into clustering to identify the various color populations and from them infer noisiness?